# Apply client-side filter on DT from server-side call to datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to render a datatable with a pre-set filter, so the user can change the filter. And I want to avoid using extra UIs such as a selectInput etc.

**Minimal working example:**
In the following example, I would want to have a pre-set filter on the "Species" column to e.g. "virginica".

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Edgar Anderson's Iris Data"),
    DT::dataTableOutput('dt')
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$dt <- renderDataTable({
        datatable(
            iris,
            filter='top',
            options=list(dom='lritp')
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I was thinking it might be possible using `columnDefs` but alas, I cannot work out how it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should get you started:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Edgar Anderson's Iris Data"),
  DT::dataTableOutput('dt')
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$dt <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      iris,
      filter='top',
      options=list(dom='lritp',
                   searchCols = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, list(search = '["virginica"]')))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Excellent. To clarify, `searchCols` takes a list for each column (including rownames), and we either pass it `NULL` for nothing or a list with search-options. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution I found, not as elegant as @ismirsehregal, was by using proxies. This requires defining an extra object per table and adding them to a reactive flow or observer.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Edgar Anderson's Iris Data"),
  DT::dataTableOutput('dt')
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  dtproxy <- dataTableProxy('dt')
  output$dt <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      iris,
      filter='top',
      options=list(dom='lritp')
    )
  })
  observe({
    updateSearch(dtproxy, keywords=list(global=NULL, columns=c(rep('',5), '["virginica"]')))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```